Is a USB power adapter a more unstable source of power than a computer?
When I use my mini PC to power my ESP32-C3 and HX711, my load cell readings are somewhat stable.
But if I use a USB power adapter (my phone's) as a power supply, my load cell readings become more erratic.
What could explain this?
In both situation, my multimeter reads 3.32 all the time (even when the HX711 connects to Wi-Fi).
In both situations, my oscilloscope shows the same amount of noise (almost flat when not connected to Wi-Fi. And some spikes when connected to Wi-Fi).

Is that a no-name/off-brand USB power adapter? They can be pretty bad.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I have many. Like the ones that come with Vivo, HTC, etc. phones.

Load cell is a sensitive analog application. For sensitive circuits like these, you would want to build your own power supply filter, ideally with both common and differential mode filtering. In general, you simply can't expect to be able to plug the circuit into a random power supply and get high performance. Sure, some power supplies or PCs may be more or less noisy, but they're never designed to be low-noise analog power supplies.

@比尔盖子 Oh my god... I connected my USB hub to the USB power adapter and my ESP32-C3 to the USB hub... and now the readings are as stable as when using my computer as power supply (I think even more stable). What could be the reason? Maybe the USB hub has those filters you mentioned?

@wyc Can be many reasons, but it's probably common-mode current. When you use the PC to power the ESP32, there's only one return path - current goes from the PC into the MCU, back to the PC (at Earth ground potential). When you use an external PSU, there are two paths, some currents comes from the PC and returns to Earth ground via PC, some currents comes from the power supply and returns to the Earth ground via the AC outlet. Any voltage differences between these two paths becomes common-mode noise. Finally, when you use a powered USB Hub, there's only one return path from MCU to Hub.

@比尔盖子 Thanks for the detailed explanation. You should write an answer.

@wyc Will do. Drawing schematics right now...

@比尔盖子 By the way, the USB hub works only at times. The rest of the time, I'm still getting the unstable load cell readings (just like connecting the circuit directly to the USB power adapter).

In short, and assuming a few things, the answer is that the computer is likely a better power supply, for your specific task.
My assumptions are:

The computer is a deskop computer and it has an internal power supply, and it has a three-prong mains plug which is connected to a mains outlet that provides the earth/ground connection (PE). In that scenario the power supply output voltage negative terminal and the PE are connected together, and the 5V supply is fixed to earth potential.

The phone supply has a two-prong mains connection. It still ouputs 5V, however the 5V output is floating because it is not fixed to any other potential, or worse, there is an Y capacitor for EMI suppression between mains side and the 5V side and it forces the 5V to ride on top of some portion of the mains AC voltage.


You can measure this yourself, by using the multimeter and measure AC voltage from your ESP32 to mains earth connection. You likely get 0 VAC when powered by PC and likely get a lot more VAC when powered by the phone supply.
So, in technical terms, the USB charger output has common mode voltage that causes small currents in the sensor wires because they have stray capacitance to surrounding earth potential, and that's what the sensor chip measures.
In practice the PC 5V may have less ripple and noise too, than the 5V from the phone supply.
Sometimes you can even feel this CM voltage. If you have a metallic phone being charged and also a metallic laptop that is being charged, and you touch both of them, you may feel the mains frequency as mild vibration, or if the situationg is nasty, even a burning sting that may scare you.

Thanks for the answer. So how do you you suggest solving the issue with the phone supply? Or do you suggest another kind of power supply that's as stable as a computer's?

@wyc Any two prong 5V supply may work or be problematic. You can buy them until you find out one that works for your case, or you may never find one. But two prong USB supplies from reputable phone vendors don't genrally cause tingles but two prong supplies that are cheap and from unknown brands are likely to tingle. Because more money is put into design and components of the circuit. Try any supply with 3 prong inlet, they genrally tie the output supply GND to PE, either directly or through some impedace like 470 ohms or 3.3k.

I discovered something: it's not about the power supply. Something becomes corrupted when I unplug and plug the USB cable, which is cleaned when I reset the ESP32-C3. Weird, I thought unplugging and plugging would reset everything, even corrupted stuff.

@wyc It can happen if the development board has a crude Power-On Reset (POR) circuit. One is supposed to use voltage supervisors to do this, simple RC circuits on the /RESET lines are not acceptable - slow-rising voltages often cause improper resets. Yet 90% of the development boards are doing exactly this. If your MCU has Under-Voltage Lockout / Brown-Out Detector feature, try enabling it and use a high voltage threshold. During program startup, send RESET to all external modules if you can (but if their RESET lines are not always exposed)...

@wyc Recommended Reading: The Least Interesting Circuit in the World

@比尔盖子 Thanks for the info again! I'll check out that link.
